# Why my compare() method can not refer to a model class field or method?

Tags: java, compare, comparator

I did defined Employee class with name and getSalary() method, but when I define MyComparator, it recognize emp1 and emp2 as Employee class
but will not recognize name and getSalary() method (dundefined).

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyComparator<Employee> implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {

        String s = emp1.name;

        if (emp1.getSalary() < emp2.getSalary()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (emp1.getSalary() == emp2.getSalary()) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return 1;

    } // compare method

} // MyComparator class

public class Employee {

    private int salary;
    public String name;

    Employee(String n, int s) {
        salary = s;
        name = n;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the two `Employee` class is the same? You can have different classes with the same name in different packages.

Comment: I do have only one Employee class, and the problem is solved by following Valentin Cavel suggestion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, i did not catch the generic type parameter. Nice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be :

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

@Override
public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {

    String s = emp1.name;

    if (emp1.getSalary() < emp2.getSalary()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (emp1.getSalary() == emp2.getSalary()) {
        return 0;
    } else
        return 1;

   } // compare method

}
```

You have to replace `MyComparator<Employee>` by `MyComparator`

You were actually defining a new generics, not using the one created by comparator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I copy my code, the generics are gone, it should read like this: public class MyComparator<Employee> implements Comparator<Employee> {...

Comment: You have to replace MyComparator<Employee> by MyComparator

Comment: One thing I still do not understand, if I put emp1.instanceOf(), which will return me Employee class, but when I try to get access to emp1.name or emp1.getSalary(), it said undefined.

Comment: I would say that by doing this you are actually creating a generics with the name "Employee". So yes, the name is "Employee", but it is the name of the generics, not of the class "Employee" that you defined.

Comment: You could put MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<Employee> that it would do the same thing!